# Count how many first and last entries in given period of time are equal

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, postgresql, hql

Given a table structured like that:

```
id   | news_id(fkey)|    status      |    date
1          10          PUBLISHED      2016-01-10
2          20          UNPUBLISHED    2016-01-10
3          10          UNPUBLISHED    2016-01-12
4          10          PUBLISHED      2016-01-15
5          10          UNPUBLISHED    2016-01-16
6          20          PUBLISHED      2016-01-18
7          10          PUBLISHED      2016-01-18
8          20          UNPUBLISHED    2016-01-20
9          30          PUBLISHED      2016-01-20
10         30          UNPUBLISHED    2016-01-21
```

I'd like to count distinct news that, in given period time, had first and last status equal(and also status equal to given in query)

So, for this table query from 2016-01-01 to 2016-02-01 would return:

- 1 (with `WHERE status = 'PUBLISHED'`) because news_id 10 had PUBLISHED in both first( 2016-01-10 ) and last row (2016-01-18)
- 1 (with `WHERE status = 'UNPUBLISHED'` because news_id 20 had UNPUBLISHED in both first and last row

notice how news_id = 30 does not appear in results, as his first/last statuses were contrary.

I have done that using following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (news_id)
    news_id, status as first_status
    FROM news_events
    where date >= '2015-11-12 15:01:56.195'
    ORDER BY news_id, date
) first
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (news_id)
    news_id, status as last_status
    FROM news_events
    where date >= '2015-11-12 15:01:56.195'
    ORDER BY news_id, date DESC

) last
using (news_id)
where first_status = last_status
and first_status = 'PUBLISHED'
```

Now, I have to transform query into SQL our internal Java framework, unfortunately it does not support subqueries, except when using `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`. I was told to transform the query to one using `EXISTS` clause(if it is possible) or try finding another solution. I am, however, clueless. Could anyone help me do that?

edit: As I am being told right now, the problem lies not with our framework, but in Hibernate - if I understood correctly, "you cannot join an inner select in HQL" (?)

Comment: This is rather hard to do without subqueries.  Possible, but challenging.  The interface to the database should probably be fixed so you can harness the full power of SQL.

Comment: Need more explanation.

Comment: @Monty What would you like me to explain?

Comment: just show me what output you want from table structed you posted in your question.

Comment: can you use `CTE\with clause` ??

Comment: @Monty it would return 1 when used with `WHERE status = 'PUBLISHED'`, as news_id = 10 has both first and last status equal to 'PUBLISHED'. it would also return 1 when used with `WHERE status = 'UNPUBLISHED'` because news_id = 20 has both statuses = 'UNPUBLISHED'. news_id = 30 does not change any of the results, because it was published and then unpublished(so the status of the news with id 30 did not change at all in this period of time)

Comment: @springenthusiast i was expecting you show me query output of your question. edit your question and write what output you want from your table structure like : id   | news_id(fkey)|    status      |    date
1          10          PUBLISHED      2016-01-10

Comment: can you use window functions?

Comment: The joys of using an obfuscation layer... Can't you just use a native query to overcome the limits of HQL?

Comment: you can use WITH OR CASE instead of inner join in your query.

Comment: @springenthusiast According to your question you want output like this : 

id   | news_id(fkey)|    status      |    date    | count
1          10          PUBLISHED      2016-01-10     3
2          20          UNPUBLISHED    2016-01-10     2

Please confirm me is it right ?

Comment: @Monty: No. springenthusiast only wants the number of news IDs for which the first and the last status in the given range is the given status. So the result for status 'PUBLISHED' and range = January 2016 would be 1 for instance.

Comment: @ThornsterKettner yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, subqueries are a substantial part of SQL. A framework forbidding their use is a bad framework.

However, "first" and "last" can be expressed with NOT EXISTS: where not exists an earlier or later entry for the same news_id and date range.

```
select count(*)
from mytable first
join mytable last on last.news_id = first.news_id
where date between @from and @to
and not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable before_first
  where before_first.news_id = first.news_id
  and before_first.date < first.date
  and before_first.date >= @from
)
and not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable after_last
  where after_last.news_id = last.news_id
  and after_last.date > last.date
  and after_last.date <= @to
)
and first.status = @status
and last.status = @status;
```

Comment: from what I have heard, it is a hibernate/hql issue.

Comment: this did the trick, although I recreated the beginning to something like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable first, mytable last WHERE last.news_id = first.news_id`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that does the same. `mytable first, mytable last` is the pre-1992 syntax for `mytable first cross join mytable last`. And the filter goes completely to the where clause then, correct. This way or the other, this query is much more complicated then need be, but that's due to the HQL restrictions and not our fault :-)

Comment: Note: `@` does not exist in postgres. (and neither in sql92, IMHO)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this adresses you problem correctly, since it is more of a workaround. But considering the following:

News need to be published before they can be "unpublished". So if you'd add 1 for each "published" and substract 1 for each "unpublished" your balance will be positive (or 1 to be exact) if first and last is "published". It will be 0 if you have as many unpublished as published and negative, if it has more unpublished than published (which logically cannot be the case but obviously might arise, since you set a date threshhold in the query where a 'published' might be occured before).

You might use this query to find out:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE status WHEN 'PUBLISHED' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS 'publishbalance'
FROM news_events
WHERE date >= '2015-11-12 15:01:56.195'
GROUP BY news_id
```

Comment: That's great thinking. This is certainly worth considering.

Comment: that is really clever workaround, thanks, although in another part of application, instead of counting, I have to select all distinct news_id's. Would it be possible in your query?

Comment: Kind of: Considering the values are alternating (strictly), first and last will be equal with a non-zero-balance but different whith a zero balance.

Comment: Exactly, one would look for news having count(status=@status) > count(status≠@status). Only problem I see: after we found such news, we would have to count them. Two steps, where we'd usually do the first step in a *subquery* :-(

Answer (score 1):

NOT EXISTS to the rescue:

```
SELECT ff.id ,ff.news_id ,ff.status , ff.zdate AS startdate
        , ll.zdate AS enddate
FROM newsflash ff
JOIN newsflash ll
        ON ff.news_id = ll.news_id
        AND ff.status = ll.status
        AND ff.zdate < ll.zdate
        AND  NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM newsflash nx
                WHERE nx.news_id = ff.news_id
                AND nx.zdate >= '2016-01-01' AND nx.zdate < '2016-02-01'
                AND (nx.zdate < ff.zdate OR nx.zdate > ll.zdate)
                )
ORDER BY ff.id
        ;
```